# Calculate probabilities in a probability tree

Tags: python-3.x, probability

I have the following dictionary:

```
dict = {1000021: [[0.6, [1000024, 1, -2]], [0.4, [1000022, 21]]],
        1000024: [[0.7, [1000022, 11, -12]], [0.3, [1000022, 2, -1]]]}
```

which corresponds to the following probability tree:

[image]

Starting from `1000021`, I now need to calculate all the probabilities and list of numbers that I get for every possible endpoint. Whenever there is a number with a dictionary entry, I need to follow that path. The dictionary can have a random number of entries and a random number of sublists. Desired output:

```
[0.4, [1000022, 21]],
[0.42, [1000022, 11, -12, 1, -2]],
[0.18, [1000022, 2, -1, 1, -2]
```

I tried to do this with a recursive function, but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

I wasn't clear in my first example, since it might have lead to the assumption, that only the first element in the sublist could have a dictionary entry, while all of them actually can have one. The answer given by Copperfield works for the example above, but it does not work for e.g.

```
mydata = {1: [[.9, [2,3]], [.1, [4,5]]],
          4: [[.2, [6,7]], [.5, [8,9]], [.3, [10,11,12]]],
          5: [[.4, [13,14]], [.6, [15,16]]]}
```

where I expect the output to be:

```
[0.9, [2, 3]],
[0.008, [6, 7, 13, 14]],
[0.012, [6, 7, 15, 16]],
[0.02, [8, 9, 13, 14]],
[0.03, [8, 9, 15, 16]],
[0.012, [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],
[0.018, [10, 11, 12, 15, 16]]
```

Comment: that don't look like a tree to me...

Comment: There is a much simpler way than the answer, if I had the time to write the demo code: Fenwick trees. They're useful for prefix sums, which is what I think you're looking for. Also, inserting a new value into a Fenwick tree and updating the corresponding prefix sum is ~4 lines of code. If I have time later today, I'll try to post some code for you.

Comment: @ScottM I looked at Fenwick Trees and it could be what I'm looking for. I don't understand them well enough to be sure though. I would appreciate if you had the time to show me an easy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that far from a tree, but how about this

```
import copy

mydata = {1000024: [[0.7, [1000022, 11, -12]], [0.3, [1000022, 2, -1]]], 
          1000021: [[0.6, [1000024, 1, -2]], [0.4, [1000022, 21]]]}

def prob_tree(data,ini,prob=1):
    data=copy.deepcopy(data)
    val=data.pop(ini,None)
    if val:
        for lst in val:
            if lst[1][0] in data:
                extra=lst[1][1:]
                for x in data[lst[1][0]]:
                    x[1].extend(extra)
                prob_tree(data,lst[1][0],lst[0])
            else:
                print( prob*lst[0],lst[1])

prob_tree(mydata,1000021)
```

output

```
0.42 [1000022, 11, -12, 1, -2]
0.18 [1000022, 2, -1, 1, -2]
0.4 [1000022, 21]
```

**EDIT**

In a inspiration struck and the use of a little of functional style here is the new version

```
import itertools, functools

def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    # Direct from the recipes in itertools documentation
    t1, t2 = itertools.tee(iterable)
    return itertools.filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)


def prob_tree(data,ini) -> (float,tuple):
    """Generator of all end points of the probability tree contained 
       in data, starting with ini"""
    for prob,path in data[ini]:
        no_more,more = map(tuple,partition(lambda x: x in data, path))
        if more:
            for node in itertools.product( *[prob_tree(data,x) for x in more] ):
                new_prob,new_path = functools.reduce(lambda acum,new: (acum[0]*new[0],acum[1]+new[1]),node,(prob,tuple()))
                yield new_prob, no_more + new_path
        else:
            yield prob, no_more

mydata = {1: [[.9, [2,3]], [.1, [4,5]]],
          4: [[.2, [6,7]], [.5, [8,9]], [.3, [10,11,12]]],
          5: [[.4, [13,14]], [.6, [15,16]]]
          }

mydata2 = {1: [[.8, [2,3]], [.1, [4,5]],[.05, [2,4]],[.05,[5,6]] ],
          4: [[.2, [6,7]], [.5, [8,9]], [.3, [10,11,12]]],
          5: [[.4, [13,14]], [.6, [15,16]]]
          }

mydata3 = {1: [[.8, [2,3]], [.1, [4,5]],[.05, [2,4]],[.05,[5,6]] ],
          4: [[.2, [6,7]], [.5, [8,9]], [.3, [10,11,12]]],
          5: [[.4, [13,14]], [.6, [15,16]]],
          13:[[.58,[23,32]],[.42,[42]] ], 
          16:[ [.9,[17,18]], [.1,[20,21]] ],
          }
```

output

```
>>> for x in prob_tree(mydata,1):
    print(x)


(0.9, (2, 3))
(0.008000000000000002, (6, 7, 13, 14))
(0.012000000000000002, (6, 7, 15, 16))
(0.020000000000000004, (8, 9, 13, 14))
(0.03, (8, 9, 15, 16))
(0.012, (10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
(0.018, (10, 11, 12, 15, 16))
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for x in prob_tree(mydata2,1):
    print(x)


(0.8, (2, 3))
(0.008000000000000002, (6, 7, 13, 14))
(0.012000000000000002, (6, 7, 15, 16))
(0.020000000000000004, (8, 9, 13, 14))
(0.03, (8, 9, 15, 16))
(0.012, (10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
(0.018, (10, 11, 12, 15, 16))
(0.010000000000000002, (2, 6, 7))
(0.025, (2, 8, 9))
(0.015, (2, 10, 11, 12))
(0.020000000000000004, (6, 13, 14))
(0.03, (6, 15, 16))
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for x in prob_tree(mydata3,1):
    print(x)


(0.8, (2, 3))
(0.004640000000000001, (6, 7, 14, 23, 32))
(0.003360000000000001, (6, 7, 14, 42))
(0.010800000000000002, (6, 7, 15, 17, 18))
(0.0012000000000000001, (6, 7, 15, 20, 21))
(0.0116, (8, 9, 14, 23, 32))
(0.008400000000000001, (8, 9, 14, 42))
(0.027000000000000003, (8, 9, 15, 17, 18))
(0.003, (8, 9, 15, 20, 21))
(0.006959999999999999, (10, 11, 12, 14, 23, 32))
(0.00504, (10, 11, 12, 14, 42))
(0.0162, (10, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18))
(0.0018, (10, 11, 12, 15, 20, 21))
(0.010000000000000002, (2, 6, 7))
(0.025, (2, 8, 9))
(0.015, (2, 10, 11, 12))
(0.0116, (6, 14, 23, 32))
(0.008400000000000001, (6, 14, 42))
(0.027000000000000003, (6, 15, 17, 18))
(0.003, (6, 15, 20, 21))
>>>
```

**EDIT 2**
adding check for circular references

```
def prob_tree_with_check(data,ini,visited=frozenset()):
    """Generator of all end points of the probability tree contained 
       in data, starting with ini. Check if a previously visited branch
       of the tree is visited again and raise RuntimeError in that case"""
    if ini in visited:
        raise RuntimeError("Branch allready visited: %r"%ini)
    visited = visited.union((ini,))
    for prob,path in data[ini]:
        no_more,more = map(tuple,partition(lambda x: x in data,path))
        if more:
            for node in itertools.product( *[prob_tree_with_check(data,x,visited) for x in more] ):
                new_prob,new_path = functools.reduce(lambda acum,new: (acum[0]*new[0],acum[1]+new[1]),node,(prob,tuple()))
                yield new_prob, no_more + new_path
        else:
            yield prob, no_more

mydata_bad = {1: [[.9, [2,3]], [.1, [4,5]]],
          4: [[.2, [6,7]], [.5, [8,9]], [.3, [10,11,12]]],
          5: [[.4, [13,14]], [.6, [15,16,1]]] # <-- try to go back to 1
          }
```

output

```
>>> for x in prob_tree_with_check(mydata_bad,1):
    x


(0.9, (2, 3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    for x in prob_tree_with_check(mydata_bad,1):
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Python Scripts\stackoverflow_test.py", line 137, in prob_tree_with_check
    for node in itertools.product( *[prob_tree_with_check(data,x,visited) for x in more] ):
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Python Scripts\stackoverflow_test.py", line 137, in prob_tree_with_check
    for node in itertools.product( *[prob_tree_with_check(data,x,visited) for x in more] ):
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Python Scripts\stackoverflow_test.py", line 132, in prob_tree_with_check
    raise RuntimeError("Branch already visited: %r"%ini)
RuntimeError: Branch already visited: 1
>>>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks. I'll have to test it with further data but then will probably accept your answer. What do you mean by it doesn't look like a tree? The input data? When I talked about tree, I meant the probability tree, maybe I'm using the wrong terminology here.

Comment: what I mean by that is what I put in my edit just now

Comment: I just realized that this won't work when there are additional dictionaries, for e.g. `11`.

Comment: ofcourse not, It only check for the first element of the sublist because that was the impression I get from the example...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't clear. Basically every element in the list can have a dictionary entry.

Comment: well, put a better example so I can make the correct adjustment.

Comment: I edited my question. I will add a bounty to the question that you can have if you solve it. I really struggle on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I need to wait till tomorrow till I can add the bounty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99959/discussion-between-copperfield-and-pfnuesel).

Comment: Your solution works fine, but I get a memory error after a while. My real life data is much bigger, around 20 dictionary entries and the lists usually have around 15 entries. There are just too many `prob_tree()` calls.

Comment: mmm, you sure you don't have circular references, right?

Comment: I guess you're right, otherwise it wouldn't take up so much memory. But I cannot find any problem with the data. Is there an easy way to check the data for consistency?

Comment: you can keep a list of the visited node and check if you try to visit one again

Comment: Still doesn't work. The following data just seems to run forever: http://pastebin.com/ifGVjciV with or without check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100171/discussion-between-copperfield-and-pfnuesel).

Comment: Your solution does not handle cases where sets can be reached through different paths. Example:
`mydata = {1: [[0.5, [2, 3]], [0.5,[10,11]]], 2: [[0.5, [4]], [0.5, [5]]], 3: [[0.5, [6]], [0.5, [7]]], 10: [[0.5, [7]], [0.5, [6]]], 11: [[0.5, [4]], [0.5, [5]]]}`
The output is:
`(0.125, (4, 6))
(0.125, (4, 7))
(0.125, (5, 6))
(0.125, (5, 7))
(0.125, (7, 4))
(0.125, (7, 5))
(0.125, (6, 4))
(0.125, (6, 5))`

while the correct output should be:
`(0.25, (4, 6))
(0.25, (4, 7))
(0.25, (5, 6))
(0.25, (5, 7))`